# perl: replace string over ssh from a bash script

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I need to replace a string in a file on a remote server with this:

```
ssh username@${TARGETSERVER} -i /path/to/ssh-key perl -p -i -e "s#\$user = \'${SDBUSER}\'\;#\$user = \'${TDBUSER}\'\;#g"  ${TARGETDIR}/configuration.php
```

That would replace the db user on a remote server in a joomla installation, btw.

If I execute that interactively on the remote server with all the variables filled, it IS working.

If I put the above line in a bash script, I get this message and no replacement takes place:

```
"Substitution pattern not terminated at -e line 1."
```

Any clue how I can make this work? I've already tried several escapes like \\' and so forth, but I didn't succeed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try '{' ? like:

's{'"$1"'}{'"$2"'}g'

Comment: I've tried this: REPLOLD="\$user = \'${SDBUSER}\'\;#";
REPLNEW="\$user = \'${TDBUSER}\'\;#";
ssh username@${TARGETSERVER} -i /path/to/ssh-key perl -p -i -e 's{'"$REPLOLD"'}{'"$REPLNEW"'}g'  ${TARGETDIR}/configuration.php  .... but didn't work :( ==> Substitution pattern not terminated at -e line 1.

Comment: @SohamA see solution down below, but thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BINGO - Got it working:

```
ssh -T username@${TARGETSERVER} -i /path/to/ssh-key <<EOI
  perl -p -i -e "s#\$user = \'${SDBUSER}\'\;#\$user = \'${TDBUSER}\'\;#g"  ${TARGETDIR}/configuration.php
  exit
EOI
```

From there, I could add several perl commands so I wouldn't have to have the payload of sshing in each time.